# Keep video resolution on small screen

Tags: jquery, css, video

I am using video tag for displaying my video but my video resolution is decreasing on a small screen. I am not able to see the video text on a small screen.
I am using below CSS and HTML for displaying my video.

HTML

```
<video width="440px" loop="true" autoplay="" muted="" preload="auto">
  <source src="footage1_generic_screenadded.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS

```
video {
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of solution you're expecting for this. The video will scale down to fill the extents of the screen. If you want the video to be bigger, then do you want zoom functionality? Or do you want to have the video at a larger size and crop a visible portion of it and let the user drag around to read parts of the video? Neither are really workable. External captions, or bigger more legible text in the video itself would be better choices.

Comment: @Pete when I remove height then I don't have any changes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to see my video at a large size

Comment: Ok, so why can you not make it larger?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were using object fit.  If you want it to be responsive but the text in it is illegible on smaller screens, surely that's just a problem with the video text being too small in the first place.

Comment: I want to cover all part of my video.
If I make it larger or zoom then maybe some part cropped or lost from my video

Comment: Exactly. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your own mp4 video source instead mp4 link given in the below codepen example in a iframe with the same styling what you tried and I hope this will help your issue:

Here is the code pen link for it [Video Sample](https://codepen.io/sniperdumbooo/pen/zYOKvYe)

```
<iframe style="-o-object-fit: cover; object-fit: cover; width: 100%; margin: 0; height: 100%;"
    src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/Sintel.mp4" frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen >
</iframe>
```